# Validate a form that contains a Google Maps field

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, forms, jquery-validate

Hi
I'm building a form to register users in a web application (php).
The form should have a google maps map where user should set his location and address.

Is there any API or code I could take to validate this field with jQuery or common JavaScript? **I must be sure that the new user sets any location before submitting the form**

I've seen this example, and would need something similar but for jQuery

http://phpformclass.com/phpform/examples/mapmarker

Thanks!

Comment: did you even bother reading the docs?

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for jquery map plugins?If yes try [jmapping](http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/) and [gmap](http://gmap.nurtext.de/).If you want to implement by yourself try to begin reading the [google maps api documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html).
To validate the point i would use i.e. regex to make sure that  the coords are valid
Cheers

Comment: I'm looking for anything. From coding by myself to a JQuery plugin. Anything will be useful, so I'll check the links you posted. Thanks!